# Wrap wkhtmltoimage to xvfb-run

Tags: wkhtmltoimage, imgkit

How can I use `wkhtmltoimage` to run by default with `xvfb`?

```
/usr/bin/xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 1024x1024x24"
```

I've to create bash file like this `wkhtmltoimage`

```
/usr/bin/xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 1024x1024x24" /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage-64 $*
```

But in this case, other programs (`gem imgkit`) do not work correctly with `wkhtmltoimage`. It put addition debug info to the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper script as I done that:

wkhtmltoimage:

```
xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 1024x680x24" wkhtmltoimage.bin -q --use-xserver $*
```

where wkhtmltoimage.bin is original binary.

Comment: Where are you place wkhtmltoimage.bin and it auto run? Can you show me more detail ?

Comment: You should place it somewhere in your PATH.